# Verify downloaded deb packages

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

I have a bunch of `.deb` files I want to verify their checksums How can I do this? they were downloaded from official repos.

Comment: All I know is that you can calculate hash of any file easily by installing the package `nautilus-gtkhash` (For Nautilus file manager which is default on Ubuntu). After installing, right click on any file and select Properties, there should be a tab for calculating hashes. Or, you can open the GTKHash app (installed automatically with nautilus-gtkhash) and do it from there.

Comment: Yes I can do that using Dolphin or Terminal but that will make it very lengthy process. Calculating md5sum matching it with md5sum from index file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick bash script that does that. I don't know if it will fit your requirements

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo ":: Checking package integrity in current directory"

for p in *.deb; do
    pkg=`echo $p|cut -f 1 -d '_'`
    sha256=`apt-cache show $pkg|grep SHA256|head -1|cut -f 2 -d ' '`
    csha256=`sha256sum $p|cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    if [[ "$csha256" == "$sha256" ]] ;then
        echo "$p: OK"
    else
        echo "$p: failed"
    fi
done
```

Comment: apt-cache shows 2 record for same package so it is showing failed for packages with good MD5sum.

Comment: I added a quick fix, but  I don't know if it will fix it for you

Comment: what if .deb package is not available in cache ?